# Meu tipo struct não é reconhecido dentro da minha classe

Tags: c++, struct

Gente, estou fazendo a implementação de uma pilha com ponteiros em C++ e tenho o seguinte código por enquanto:

```
template <class T>
struct Node {
    T item;
    Node *prox;
};

class Pilha {
    private:
    int tamanho;
    Node *topo;

    public:
    Pilha() {
    this->topo=NULL;
    this->tamanho=0;    
}
```

No atributo privado **topo**, o tipo **Node** não está sendo reconhecido dentro da minha classe **Pilha**. O eclipse retorna o seguinte erro: **Type 'Node' could not be resolved**.

O que pode ser? Obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a sua estrutura `Node` tem um `template`, que vai ser utilizado para criar um `Node` de qualquer tipo, logo é preciso utilizar também esse padrão na classe `Pilha` para o compilador saber que o tipo de `Node` pode variar:

```
template <class T>
struct Node {
    T item;
    Node *prox;
};

template <class T> // indicação que esta classe tambem usa template
class Pilha {
private:
    int tamanho;
    Node<T> *topo; //aqui o Node é indicado com <T> 

public:
    Pilha() {
        this->topo=NULL;
        this->tamanho=0;
    }
};
```

No código acima, comentei apenas nos locais que alterei.

Vale lembrar que quando for instanciar um nó tem usar a de notação do template. Exemplo:

```
Node<T> *novoNo = new Node<T>();
```

Em c++ também tem uma melhor alternativa para `NULL` que é [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) e que é um literal de ponteiro e lhe evita algumas conversões implícitas que em determinadas situações geram problemas.

Comment: Eu tenho que colocar o **<T>** no **Node *topo** , tanto na struct qnt no atributo privado na pilha? Obg!

Comment: @lineOut Sim, porque sempre que usa um valor com template numa classe, a classe tem de passar a usar template também, senão não tinha como especificar que queria uma `Pilha<int>` ou uma `Pilha<double>`. Nesse caso quando instância `Pilha<int>` vai forçar `Node<int>`.

Comment: Eu fiz isso mas dentro da pilha ta retornando erro: **Type 'Node<T>' could not be resolved** ... mesmo eu tendo colocado também a indicação de template na Pilha. Na struct não deu erro.

Comment: @lineOut Veja o exemplo do código na minha resposta sem erros [no Ideone](https://ideone.com/1zDfIA). Deixei inclusivamente uma instanciação de um novo nó no construtor a titulo de exemplo.

Comment: Funcionou... Obrigada @Isac !! ^^